# Переменные среды Windows на удаленном компьютере через реестр программно

Tags: windows, реестр, переменные-среды

Потребовалось узнать переменные среды на удаленном компьютере. В том числе, в частности, %SYSTEМDRIVE%. С локальным все понятно - getenv. 
Чтобы найти на уделенном, начал смотреть в реестре. Нашел почти все мне нужное: APPDATA, LOCALAPPDATA нашел в  Shell Folders, SYSTEMROOT в CurrentVersion, а вот SYSTEMDRIVE его нет. Конечно можно выбрать и из systemroot, но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли в чистом виде. Так же не нашел ALLUSERSPROFILE в чистом виде.

Answer (score 1):

Масса вариантов (программно WMI напрямую, либо через PowerShell, через PowerShell Invoke, через WMIC...).

Например, powershell, получить %SYSTEMDRIVE%:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName Ваш_компьютер | Select PSComputerName,SystemDrive
```

или в нём же через Invoke:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Ваш_компьютер {$env:COMPUTERNAME; $env:SystemDrive; dir $env:SystemDrive}
```

Не забудьте подставить значение вместо *"Ваш_компьютер"*.

Так же можно обратиться и ко всем другим переменным. Либо ко всем сразу, что-то вроде:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Ваш_компьютер {Get-ChildItem -Path Env:* | Sort-Object Name}
```

Comment: требуется ТОЛЬКО через реест и программно

Comment: Ну если через реестр, то чем Вас не устраивает переменная в ветви **"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"** по имени **"SystemRoot"**, из первых символов которой можно получить значение, совпадающее с значением переменной **SYSTEMDRIVE**?

Comment: **%ALLUSERPROFILE%** соответствует **"Common AppData"** в ветви **SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders**. Что является нормой как для WinXP, так и поздних Win7/8/Vista

Comment: Я же написал "SYSTEMROOT в CurrentVersion, а вот SYSTEMDRIVE его нет. Конечно можно выбрать и из systemroot, но хотелось бы узнать, есть ли в чистом виде".   А "%ALLUSERPROFILE% == Common AppData"  я действительно прогладел

Comment: В чистом виде в реестре Вы не найдете **SYSTEMDRIVE**, лишь косвенно. Так что основной вариант - извлечь значение, оперируя значениями других переменных. но ведь обращаюсь к реестру  Вы будете работать через определенный интерфейс. И я думаю, там могут найтись средства, чтобы оперировать с выгруженными/найденными значениями параметров.